# PHP and XMPP both way

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, client, xmpp

I'm trying to create a web application with PHP and XMPP. One of the requirements is that when the Javascript client on the browser sends an event to the server through XMPP, the PHP gets to work and serves that request. As you know, XMPP allows its clients to "listen" for various types of events and jump to life when they find the right event. Of course PHP is only alive for the duration of an HTTP request, so according to my research PHP XMPP clients are only "one way" - ie they can only generate events and not listen for and consume them.

My questions for the experts are: 
 1. Is my research correct? Is PHP/XMPP only one-way?
 2. Is there any way to go around this problem with PHP?
 3. Does Ruby on Rails have the same issue, or does it work with XMPP in a "two-way" manner?

Thanks a lot, I appreciate any help on this!

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are trying to use PHP as an XMPP server, which would be problematic. It is probably doable in Rails, but wouldn't be ideal.

It might be worth having a look at one of the many open-source XMPP platforms like [ejabberd](http://www.ejabberd.im/).

Comment: Agreed and there are others, I've used openfire. http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/

Answer (score 0):

I didn't really understood what exactly you mean by "one way using PHP/XMPP". However, from my experience there is no restriction what so ever if you choose to work with PHP+XMPP combination, where your browser clients uses some kind of xmpp javascript library.

Here is generally how the flow will be with PHP/XMPP setup:

1. Browser sends an ajax poll
2. PHP script on your web server receives this ajax poll
3. Internally PHP script talks to the bosh end point
4. PHP script wait for a response from the server until a timeout occurs
5. On response or timeout PHP relay back response from bosh end point to your browser client

In this flow PHP script acts like a connection manager between your browser and jabber server. Indeed under high traffic this methodology is not recommended, because soon your web server might stop accepting new ajax polls due to PHP scripts already waiting for response from bosh end point.

You can try out the [boshchat.php](https://github.com/abhinavsingh/JAXL/blob/master/app/boshchat.php) sample example from [Jaxl library](http://github.com/abhinavsingh/JAXL) which demonstrate exactly the same flow i described above.